# Lagom Cassandra read before update

Tags: cassandra, lagom

This is specific to Lagom Framework.
During an update I do not have the complete data, I have a few alternate tables which needs to be updated as well, how do I do a read from my main table, so I have all they keys to perform an update on alternate tables.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official docs on this one:

https://www.lagomframework.com/documentation/1.3.x/java/ReadSideCassandra.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you be a little more specific, I went through the documentation earlier but was not clear to me, I am doing a force read getById(id).invoke().toCompletableFuture().get(), but I was not sure if I am violating fundamental design of the framework